# Display the f.select value in another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the listing view where user select a value for his car odometer

```
<label>Odometer</label>
              <%= f.select :odometer, [["0-50Km", 1], ["50-100Km", 2], ["100-150km", 3], ["150k+", 4]],
                            id: "Odometer", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
```

I'm stuck at this point

```
<div class="col-md-4"><%= @car.odometer %></div>
```

As u can image the output in my view will be 1, 2 or 3

[outup view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj1Aw.jpg)

I wish to output the correspondig text value "0-50km" etc not 1 2 3

How can i do?
Thank u!

Comment: what type of data is @car.odometer?

Comment: Hi! It's a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :odometer, [["0-50Km", "0-50Km"], ["50-100Km", "50-100Km"], ["100-150km","100-150km"], ["150k+", "150k+"]],
                            id: "Odometer", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: Thank You!  :odometer was a string and i miss this clever solution!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends. Specifically, it depends on whether you want to keep 1, 2 or 3 as internal attribute values.

If not, you can use roshiend's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62284397/5089588) (adding some quotes to his string literals).

If you want to keep the numeric values, you must provide a data structure from which you choose the correct display value dynamically. The most basic, but also the most ugly, implementation would be:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= {1 => "0-50Km,
       2 => "50-100Km",
       3 => "100-150km",
       4 => "150km+"}[@car.odometer] %>
</div>
```

However, this violates lots of OOP principles. The minimum refactoring should look like this:

```
#models/car.rb
def Car.odometer_options
  {1 => '0-50Km',
   2 => '50-100Km',
   3 => '100-150km',
   4 => '150km+'}
end

#in your form
<%= f.select :odometer,
             Car.odometer_options.map{ |k,v| [v, k] },
             id: "Odometer",
             prompt: "Select...",
             class: "form-control" %>

#in your view
<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= Car.odometer_options[@car.odometer] %>
</div>
```

While far from a "high-end implementation", this is at least DRY-ish.